# Python Help - with “local variable referenced before assignment”

Tags: python, python-3.x

*I have had problems with the shell saying local variable referenced before assignment and don't feel any previous answers have helped. Can I have some specific advice to this code:*

> **Error** : TotalExcessCharge = ExcessOneCharge + ExcessTwoCharge + ExcessThreeCharge + ExcessFourCharge + ExcessFiveCharge + ExcessPlusLimitCharge
>   UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ExcessThreeCharge' referenced before assignment

```
def BillingSystem(CustomerName,CustomerType,TotalGBUsed):
    StandardCustomer = 1500
    StandardQuota = 25
    PremiumCustomer = 2500
    PremiumQuota = 50

    if (CustomerType == "Standard") or (CustomerType == "standard"):
        if (TotalGBUsed > StandardQuota):
            ExcessGB = TotalGBUsed - StandardQuota
            for a in range(0, ExcessGB):
                if (a <= 10):
                    ExcessOne = 250
                    ExcessOneCharge = a * ExcessOne

            for b in range(0, ExcessGB):
                if (b > 10) and (b <= 20):
                    ExcessTwo = 500
                    ExcessTwoCharge = b * ExcessTwo

            for c in range(0, ExcessGB):
                if (c > 20) and (c <= 30):
                    ExcessThree = 750
                    ExcessThreeCharge = c * ExcessThree

            for d in range(0, ExcessGB):
                if (d > 30) and (d <= 40):
                    ExcessFour = 1000
                    ExcessFourCharge = d * ExcessFour

            for e in range(0, ExcessGB):
                if (e > 40) and (e <= 50):
                    ExcessFive = 1250
                    ExcessFiveCharge = e * ExcessFive

            for explus in range(0, ExcessGB):
                if (explus > 50):
                    ExcessPlusLimit = 1500
                    ExcessPlusLimitCharge = explus * ExcessPlusLimit

        TotalExcessCharge = ExcessOneCharge + ExcessTwoCharge + ExcessThreeCharge + ExcessFourCharge + ExcessFiveCharge + ExcessPlusLimitCharge
        TotalCharge = StandardCustomer + TotalExcessCharge

        print ("Total Excess Charge : " + str(TotalExcessCharge))
        print ("Total Charge for this month : " + str(TotalCharge))

    else:
        print ("Total Excess Charge : 0")
        print ("Total Charge for this month : " + str(StandardCustomer))

CName = input("[!] Customer Name : ")
CType = input("[!] Customer Type : ")
TotGB = int(input("[!] Total GB Usage : "))
BillingSystem(CName,CType,TotGB)
```

Comment: Provide the Input you tried...

Comment: What do you expect ``ExcessThreeCharge`` to be when ``if (c > 20) and (c <= 30)`` is not satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is when your code doesn't go into the if conditions, your variables never get initiated but you have referred them at the end...So the error clearly tells you that you are calling the variable that you have never created or assigned. Always ensure that you refer the assigned variables!

And also you can make your code more easier to read like

- using Excess# values directly inside the if conditions without assigning it to a variable.
- using upper function on the input string and compare the value in one go..

```
def BillingSystem(CustomerName,CustomerType,TotalGBUsed):
    StandardCustomer = 1500
    StandardQuota = 25
    PremiumCustomer = 2500
    PremiumQuota = 50

    ExcessOneCharge=0
    ExcessTwoCharge=0
    ExcessThreeCharge=0
    ExcessFourCharge=0
    ExcessFiveCharge=0
    ExcessPlusLimitCharge=0


    if (CustomerType.upper() == "STANDARD"):
        if (TotalGBUsed > StandardQuota):
            ExcessGB = TotalGBUsed - StandardQuota
            for a in range(0, ExcessGB):
                if (a <= 10):
                    ExcessOneCharge = a * 250
                elif (a > 10) and (a <= 20):
                    ExcessTwoCharge = (a - 10) * 500
                elif (a > 20) and (a <= 30):
                    ExcessThreeCharge = (a - 20) * 750
                elif (a > 30) and (a <= 40):
                    ExcessFourCharge = (a - 30) * 1000
                elif (a > 40) and (a <= 50):         
                    ExcessFiveCharge = (a - 40) * 1250
                elif (a > 50):
                    ExcessPlusLimitCharge = (a - 50) * 1500

        TotalExcessCharge = ExcessOneCharge + 
                            ExcessTwoCharge + 
                            ExcessThreeCharge + 
                            ExcessFourCharge + 
                            ExcessFiveCharge + 
                            ExcessPlusLimitCharge

        TotalCharge = StandardCustomer + TotalExcessCharge

        print ("Total Excess Charge : ", TotalExcessCharge)
        print ("Total Charge for this month : ", TotalCharge)

    else:
        print ("Total Excess Charge : 0")
        print ("Total Charge for this month : ", StandardCustomer)

CName = input("[!] Customer Name : ")
CType = input("[!] Customer Type : ")
TotGB = int(input("[!] Total GB Usage : "))
BillingSystem(CName,CType,TotGB)
```

And also instead of creating ExcessOneCharge, ExcessTwoCharge variables etc... You can do something like :

```
TotalExcessCharge = 0 #don't forget to initiate the variable at the beginning of the function
#then inside the if conditions
TotalExcessCharge += a*Excess#
```

This is just an example of how to write a cleaner code...logics you can apply as per your requirements!

Note : I'm typing everything in mobile, so pls ignore typos...

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help! But there is an issue with output, if I have an excess GB of 20, it outputs 12500 instead of 7500.

Comment: You can modify the logic as required...i am travelling and currently don't have a system to check the output....

Comment: Always welcome :) Also, I have updated the code now, check it...the issue was, we have to calculate the charge only for next 10 GBs in each if case....but i didn't handle it....Hope it produces proper output now!

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, at this point:

```
TotalExcessCharge = ExcessOneCharge + ExcessTwoCharge + ExcessThreeCharge + ExcessFourCharge + ExcessFiveCharge + ExcessPlusLimitCharge
```

your `ExcessThreeCharge` variable have not yet been assigned to, and that's because you assign to it under conditional:

```
        for c in range(0, ExcessGB):
            if (c > 20) and (c <= 30):
                ExcessThree = 750
                ExcessThreeCharge = c * ExcessThree
```

which might never be satisfied if `ExcessDB` is <= 20.

I'll not advise you how to fix it because, frankly, I do not understand the underlying logic of this code - it seems completely nonsensical to me.

Comment: I apologies, i'm still a noob

Answer (score 0):

Because your definition of each of the "Excess#Charge" variables are within if statements, they seem not to be running for some reason. To fix this, I recommend defining all of the variables as 0 at the start so that if there is no excess value, it will simply be defined as 0. For example, at this at the top of the class:

```
ExcessOneCharge = 0
ExcessTwoCharge = 0
ExcessThreeCharge = 0
ExcessFourCharge = 0
ExcessFiveCharge = 0
ExcessPlusLimitCharge = 0
```

Comment: No problem. Just glad I could help.